# Always "I have no answer for that" response in program ab

Tags: aiml

I have been trying to create a chat bot using `program ab`. I have created a simple `aiml` file and tried. But It is not working. I am getting this,

```
Name = super Path = /aiml/bots/super
c:/ab
/aiml/bots
/aiml/bots/super
/aiml/bots/super/aiml
/aiml/bots/super/aimlif
/aiml/bots/super/config
/aiml/bots/super/logs
/aiml/bots/super/sets
/aiml/bots/super/maps
Preprocessor: 0 norms 0 persons 0 person2 
Get Properties: /aiml/bots/super/config/properties.txt
addAIMLSets: /aiml/bots/super/sets does not exist.
addCategories: /aiml/bots/super/aiml does not exist.
AIML modified Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1970 AIMLIF modified Thu Jan 01   05:30:00 IST 1970
No deleted.aiml.csv file found
No deleted.aiml.csv file found
addCategories: /aiml/bots/super/aimlif does not exist.
Loaded 0 categories in 0.002 sec
No AIMLIF Files found.  Looking for AIML
addCategories: /aiml/bots/super/aiml does not exist.
Loaded 0 categories in 0.001 sec
--> Bot super 0 completed 0 deleted 0 unfinished
Setting predicate topic to unknown
normalized = HELLO
No match.
writeCertainIFCaegories learnf.aiml size= 0
I have no answer for that.
```

Why the file is not loaded? I have included the simple `aiml` file also below. `super` folder have all the inbuilt `aiml` files I downloaded with `program ab`

Answer (score 0):

Because the aiml files were not loaded properly and so there are no answers to reply to any of the questions.

```
Preprocessor: 0 norms 0 persons 0 person2
```

This means no files were processed and added.

Comment: I've added a clarification below

Answer (score 0):

The .aiml files were *most likely* not loaded or found. Perhaps a naming issue??

```
Name = super Path = /aiml/bots/super
c:/ab
/aiml/bots
/aiml/bots/super
/aiml/bots/super/aiml
/aiml/bots/super/aimlif
/aiml/bots/super/config
/aiml/bots/super/logs
/aiml/bots/super/sets
/aiml/bots/super/maps
Preprocessor: 0 norms 0 persons 0 person2 
Get Properties: /aiml/bots/super/config/properties.txt
addAIMLSets: /aiml/bots/super/sets does not exist.
addCategories: /aiml/bots/super/aiml does not exist.
AIML modified Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1970 AIMLIF modified Thu Jan 01   05:30:00 IST 1970
No deleted.aiml.csv file found
No deleted.aiml.csv file found
addCategories: /aiml/bots/super/aimlif does not exist.
Loaded 0 categories in 0.002 sec
No AIMLIF Files found.  Looking for AIML
addCategories: /aiml/bots/super/aiml does not exist.
Loaded 0 categories in 0.001 sec
--> Bot super 0 completed 0 deleted 0 unfinished
Setting predicate topic to unknown
normalized = HELLO
No match.
writeCertainIFCaegories learnf.aiml size= 0
I have no answer for that.
```

The `Loaded 0 categories` tells you that no categories were found from your .aiml files
Also, `--> Bot super 0 completed 0 deleted 0 unfinished`, again tells you that 0 categories were completed for your bot

It may be that you missed out on setting up your .aiml.csv files

Hope this helps

Comment: How to change the "Path = /aiml/bots/super" , I have created a folder "/aiml/bots/test". How to set /aiml/bots/super this as the default path?